# Simple Temperature Converter

Tags: python

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this program?

-------- cut here -----------

```
import sys

def temp_converter_2(degree):
  print("Do you want to convert to Celsius or Fahrenheit? Enter C or F")
  answer = str(sys.stdin.readline())

  if answer == "C":
    converted_value = (degree - 32) * 5/9
  elif answer == "F":
    converted_value = (degree * 9/5) + 32
  else:
    print("That's not C or F")
    converted_value = -99;

  print(converted_value)

def __main__():
  print("Enter temp to convert:")
  temp = int(sys.stdin.readline())
  temp_converter_2(temp)
```

------- cut here --------

When I run it, I get nothing. I am hoping that it will ask me for input.  What am I missing?

MacBook-Pro-(9):stuff$ python temp_converter_2.py 
MacBook-Pro-(9):stuff$

Comment: You do not appear to be calling your `__main__` function. Functions need to be called for the code inside them to be executed.

Comment: Why are you using `sys.stdin.readline()` insted of `input()`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your `__main__` function for the program to get executed. So below everything put:

```
__main__()
```

Your function probably shouldn't be named `__main__` though since the double underscore functions/variables have special meanings, better name would be `main`.